# Adjusting Font size - Font Property

Tags: css, qt

I have a `QPushButton` designed with css.
I wanted him to change size on clicked. I used a `QPropertyAnimation(mybutton,"geometry")` to achieve this goal.
Yet, the size policy is fixed. To adjust this factor, I would like to use the font property of a QPushButton.

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MyButton();
};
```

And my `.ccp` :

```
MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    this->setGeometry(150,20,340,50);
    this->setStyleSheet("border-radius: 25; background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #eeeeee, stop: 1 #5F6060);");
    this->setText("Menu");
    this->setFont(QFont("Colibri",25));
    this->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

    QPalette pal;

    pal.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText,Qt::white);
    this->setPalette(pal);
}
```

I try to animate using `QPropertyAnimation` as follows :

```
animationBoutonMenuText = new QPropertyAnimation(myButton,"font");

animationBoutonMenuText->setDuration(300);
animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(0,QFont("Colibri",25));
animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(0.5,QFont("Colibri",30));
animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(1,QFont("Colibri",25));

animationBoutonMenuText->start();
```

But it doesn't work. It resets my font size on click (I guess the default value is 10 or 11 pixels) and it stays at the default size. Do you have any idea why ?

Ps : I've seen [this](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), but those `css` tags seems not to work on Qt. Am I wrong ?
This leads to another question (sorry), can we modify (meaning use the `Q_PROPERTY` macro) css factors ? Such as `border-radius`, which should change with the size of my button.

EDIT :

```
#include "mybutton.h"

QVariant myFontInterpolator(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    int a = start.pixelSize();
    int b = end.pixelSize();
    int c = (1-progress)*a + progress*b;
    QFont rt(start);
    rt.setPointSize(c);
    return (rt);
}

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    this->setGeometry(150,20,340,50);
    this->setStyleSheet("border-radius: 25; background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #eeeeee, stop: 1 #5F6060);");
    this->setText("Menu");
    this->setFont(QFont("Colibri",25));
    this->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor); 

    qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator);

    QPalette pal;

    pal.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText,Qt::white);
    this->setPalette(pal);
}

MyButton::~MyButton()
{

}
```

EDIT 2 (piece of code to get the behaviour I wanted) :

```
QVariant myFontInterpolator(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    if (progress<0.5)
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*25 + progress*30;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*30 + progress*25;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
}
```

And the animation :

```
animationBoutonMenuText = new QPropertyAnimation(boutonMenu,"font");

animationBoutonMenuText->setDuration(300);
animationBoutonMenuText->setStartValue(QFont("Colibri",25));
animationBoutonMenuText->setEndValue(QFont("Colibri",25));

animationBoutonMenuText->start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that are not correct in your code and that's why it's not working as you expect. First, the **QFont** is not in the list of **QVariantAnimation**, that means you cannot do animation with **QPropertyAnimation** and **QFont** like you do. [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) the list of possible properties.

However, you can create an interpolator to make it work. Like that (it's in the same page than the previous link).

> Not all QVariant types are supported. Below is a list of currently
>   supported QVariant types:
>
> ```
> Int
> UInt
> Double
> Float
> QLine
> QLineF
> QPoint
> QPointF
> QSize
> QSizeF
> QRect
> QRectF
> QColor
> ```
>
> If you need to interpolate other variant types, including custom
>   types, you have to implement interpolation for these yourself. To do
>   this, you can register an interpolator function for a given type. This
>   function takes 3 parameters: the start value, the end value, and the
>   current progress.
>
> Example:
>
> QVariant myColorInterpolator(const QColor &start, const QColor &end,
>   qreal progress) {
>       ...
>       return QColor(...); } ... qRegisterAnimationInterpolator(myColorInterpolator);
>
> Another option is to reimplement interpolated(), which returns
>   interpolation values for the value being interpolated.

Your border-radius is **too big**, with a value of **15**, there is a good border-radius.
So here a small code with an animation that works (but does not do exactly what you want).

test.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-06-26T12:49:54
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    mybutton.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    mybutton.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mybutton.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto myButton = new MyButton(this);
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(myButton);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mybutton.cpp:

```
#include "mybutton.h"
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

#include <QDebug>

QVariant myFontInterpolator(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    int a = start.pixelSize();
    int b = end.pixelSize();
    int c = (1-progress)*a + progress*b;
    QFont rt(start);
    rt.setPointSize(rt.pointSize() - c);
    return (rt);
}

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    this->setGeometry(150,20,340,50);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #eeeeee, stop: 1 #5F6060); border-radius: 19;");
    this->setText("Menu");
    this->setFont(QFont("Colibri", 25));
    this->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor); // Marche que au début (si on est pas passé au dessus d'autre chose)


    qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator);

    QPalette pal;

    pal.setColor(QPalette::ButtonText,Qt::white);
    this->setPalette(pal);
}




void MyButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
    auto animationBoutonMenuText = new QPropertyAnimation(this,"font");

    animationBoutonMenuText->setDuration(300);
    animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(0,QFont("Colibri",25));
    animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(0.5,QFont("Colibri",30));
    animationBoutonMenuText->setKeyValueAt(1,QFont("Colibri",25));

    animationBoutonMenuText->start();
}
```

mybutton.h:

```
#ifndef MYBUTTON_H
#define MYBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>



class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MyButton() {}
public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
};
#endif // MYBUTTON_H
```

EDIT:
 the mybutton.cpp has been updated with a font that change with the animation. I am not sure it's the animation you seek but you can start with it.

Comment: Do you have any example about how to use the interpolation system ? What type should I return to change my font size ?
Plus thank you for your example but as explained I know how to use animation with the geometry property.
Ps : Why is my border-radius "too-big" ? It is half the height, so my lateral borders are half circles and not lines

Comment: I add an animation for the font in the mybutton.cpp. it changes the size as expected for me.

Comment: I changed the implementation in my code so I have almost the same thing as you, but I have a couple of errors : QVariant incomplete, qRegisterAnimationInterpolator not declared, expected primary expression before '>' . Don't you have them ? I didn't change any of my previous code, so the declaration of the animation is the same, I am not sure it is correct.

Comment: No I don't have any errors. Be sure to add all the necessary includes. (You can see them in my code)

Comment: The <QDebug> include fixed one, but the last two remain. Did you do something to "declare" qRegisterAnimationInterpolator?

Comment: did you include #include <QPropertyAnimation> ?

Comment: Else you can just copy all the files I gave you and check if it's work for you. Then adapt them to your code. Or else give me a working sample of your code that I can compile and modify for you.

Comment: Oh you're right since my animations are in my Main I didn't in button.ccp. Thank you ! To have the behaviour I wanted I had to change my animation and "myFontInterpolator()" method. See EDIT 2.
Also, if you don't mind going on helping me, I have an other topic, also dealing with animation but on QPainterPath (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671834/animation-on-qpainterpath). 
Don't feel obliged to answer, you already helped me a lot ! Thank you again

Comment: I saw it but you don't give a code which compiles or can be compiled easily (ArrowD, ArrowB, ArrowG, ArrowH are missing etc) so if you give a code which compiles, I can help you. (or you can send it to me by email at gabriel.degrimouard@gmail.com).

Comment: I thought it was a bit long to post the whole code, I send you all my files by mail. Thank you

Comment: If you think your code is too big to write all on Stack Overflow, you could create a link to an archive of your code when you ask a question. It's really hard to answer questions without being able to do some tests (if it's not an obvious question).

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, can I do it on stock over flow directly ?

Comment: there are many websites to upload small files. just find one, add your archive and then add a link.

Comment: I'm trying GitHub, it's a failure for the moment .. !